# How to retrieve the value of multiple inputs with the same name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am displaying some information from an XML file, beside each I have buttons with allow user to delete the data.

Now I am using a hidden input field to store some information needed to process the form. All of the hidden input fields have the sane name value. When the user clicks the delete button I want to retrieve the value of the hidden filed that was clicked, but It returns the last one.

here is my code:

```
function displayPapers(){
    var courseCode = $("#subject").val();

    loadXML(courseCode, function(xmlDoc){
        $(xmlDoc).find('paper').each(function(){
            var code = $(this).find("code")[0].textContent;
            var title = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
            var semester = $(this).find("semester")[0].textContent;

            $("#papers").append("<p>" + code + ": " + title + " (S" + semester + ") " +
                                "<input type='submit' name='paperUpdate' value='Edit'>" +
                                "<input type='submit' name='paperDelete' value='Delete'>" +
                                "<input type='hidden' name='paperCode' value='" + code + "'></p>");
        })
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP code used to process the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['paperUpdate'])){
   echo $_POST['paperCode'];
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of the hidden field for which the delete button was clicked. I am not sure how to fix this. thanks.

Comment: please add your html structure. by the way .find('paper') is looking for tags <paper>, if you are looking for a class should be .find('.paper')

Comment: Please post the code you use to process the clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery DOM traversal functions to find related elements.

```
$('input[name=paperDelete]').click(function() {
    var paperCode = $(this).next().val();
    // Do something with paperCode
});
```

To be able to get all the values in PHP, you should give it a name ending in `[]`. PHP will then turn all the values into an array. So change your code to:

```
        $("#papers").append("<p>" + code + ": " + title + " (S" + semester + ") " +
                            "<input type='submit' name='paperUpdate' value='Edit'>" +
                            "<input type='submit' name='paperDelete' value='Delete'>" +
                            "<input type='hidden' name='paperCode[]' value='" + code + "'></p>");
    })
});
```

Then your PHP can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['paperCode'] as $code) {
    echo $code;
}
```

Comment: the PHP code prints the values of all the hidden fields, I just want the one that was clicked. How can i do that in PHP? thnx

Comment: What I would do is put each paragraph in a separate form, so clicking the submit button just submits that one instead of all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
$("#papers").on("click","input[name='paperDelete']",function(){
  alert($(this).siblings("input[name='paperCode']").val())
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/dbsbjxLm/)

Comment: Would this work with multiple hidden fields with same name attribute?

Comment: Yes if your html structure is like this http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/dbsbjxLm/1/, add you html too

Answer (score 0):

For multiple field with same name..Try something like this..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    $name = $_POST['nam'];
    //var_dump($name);
    echo $name[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $name[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $name[2];
}

?>
<form method='post'>
FirstName:<input type='text' name='nam[]'>
MiddleName:<input type='text' name='nam[]'>
LastName:<input type='text' name='nam[]'>
<input type="submit" value="POST" name="btn">
</form>
```